# Python: variables not cumulative passing through functions

Tags: python

I am writing a function for a text adventure I'm making that acts as a progress bar when the player receives experience (which then levels the player up upon reaching 100). For some reason altering the values of my variables inside the function does not change their values outside the function even though I've returned all three. This becomes apparent when I try calling the function twice, each time adding *85* to the variable *a*.

**Within the function, the objective is to pass the value of *a* to *b*, check if *b* is greater than or equal to *100*, if so add *1* to *c* and remove *100* from *b*, then reset *a* to *0*, *print* the result, and *return* the new values.**

***a*** = new experience *b* = current experience *c* = player level

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 1

def func_1(a, b, c):
    b = b + a
    loop1 = 0
    while loop1 < 1:
        if b >= 100:
            print(" ")
            print("Add 1!")
            print(" ")
            c = c + 1
            b = b - 100
        else:
            loop1 = loop1 + 1
        a = a - a
        print("c is " + str(c))
        print("b is " + str(b))
        print("a is " + str(a))
        return a
        return b
        return c

a = a + 85
func_1(a, b, c)
a = a + 85
func_1(a, b, c)
print a, b, c
```

I'm really new to programming so I apologize for any inefficiencies. Thank you for any help and let me know if something doesn't make sense/is unclear.

Comment: You say you're new to programming, so here's a tiny bit of advice. It is best to give variables _descriptive names_.  That way you don't have to tell us that `a` is new experience, `b` is current experience, and `c` is player level.  You can just name them `new_experience`, `current_experience`, and `player_level`.  And if you come back to your code later, you'll be very happy with yourself.  +1 from me.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I was hoping to make the problem a little more relatable by making the variables generic, but perhaps that was wrong way to go? I've been hearing a lot about how important it is to get "creative" with the names just like your saying.

Comment: You're welcome!  [Here's a link to an MIT class that helped me out a ton](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/video-lectures/) when I was first studying computer science.  I'd encourage you to watch the first one if you're interested; I know I'm glad that I did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things I see here:

First, out of the three return statements at the end of your code, only the first, `return a`, is executed. A `return` statement immediately stops execution of the function; `return b` and `return c` are never touched.

Second, you're having some confusion with the scope of the variables. `a`, `b`, and `c` defined outside of the function are *global* variables, while the `a`, `b`, and `c` passed into the function are *local* to the scope of the function. Thus, any modifications to the variables in your function won't affect the global variables.

You can do two things. First, have a global declaration at the beginning of the function:

```
def func_1():
    global a
    global b
    global c
    # Function body
```

This indicates to the function that `a`, `b`, and `c` are global variables that exist outside the function. Thus, passing in arguments is no longer needed; the function will search for variables outside the function. However, this is bad programming practice. The better option is to have `func_1` return the modified values and reassign the global values to these new values, like so:

```
def func_1(a, b, c):
    # Function body
    return (a, b, c)
```

Then, to call the function and modify the variables outside the function:

```
a, b, c = func_1(a, b, c)
```

A couple suggestions:

You have a lot of incrementing going on, and python has specialized syntax for it: `b = b + a` can be shortened to `b += a`, `c = c + 1` to `c += 1`, `b = b - 100` to `b -= 100`. Also, simply reset a to 0 with `a = 0` instead of subtracting `a - a`. Also, you don't need `print(" ")`; `print()` will suffice.

Next, your `while` loop is unnecessary. Your function only needs to check once whether `b >= 100`, so there's no need to set up a loop. Increment `b` and then use a simple `if` statement to level up if necessary:

```
def func_1(a, b, c):
    b += a
    if b >= 100:
        print("\nAdd 1!\n")
        c += 1
        b -= 100
    a = 0
    # Rest of the function
```

Comment: Really helpful. Thank you! I put the while loop in just in case b ever ended up at 200 (which would then level up the player twice).

Answer (score 0):

Inside `func_1()` the names `a,b,c` are *local*. When you change them nothing happens to the external `a,b,c`. You `return` the values correctly in the function, but then when calling the function you need to assign the values to the variables like this: `a,b,c=func_1(a,b,c)`.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a value doesn't set it unless you explicitly assign it in the calling function:

```
a, b, c = func_1(a, b, c)
```

Assigning inside the function doesn't affect the outer ones because they are considered "local scope". To counter that declare them global to affect the outer variables:

```
def func_1():
    global a
    global b
    global c
```

Only one of these should be implemented

It is generally preferred not to declare globals. Ideally you should make a class for all of this, but these two options would require the least refactoring of your existing code

Answer (score 0):

Note that a global variable (the variables outside of the function) are completely separate from the local variables (the variables inside the function).

This doesn't work because you can only return once. When you returned a, the function immediately stopped.
Also, since you didn't set any variable to the returned value, the global variables outside of the loop were unaffected. What you can do is return the a, b, and c values as a tuple, and then set the a, b and c global variables to that tuple.

```
return (a, b, c)

a, b, c = func_1(a, b, c)
```